# Stuck on Boot After Joining Microsoft Active Directory Domain

Tags: release-loki, networking

I installed Centrify and joined an Active Directory domain but now it just stays on the bootup screen. I'm using Loki.

I'm unsure how I can reach a recovery console.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in the end it did not matter elementary will not work with centrify and MS AD although all packages installed without a problem. I guess you can't use elementary os in an office environment. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a recovery mode on elementary Loki as with Ubuntu. **The GRUB menu is just hidden during startup.**

Press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key before elementary starts to show the GRUB menu and select "Advanced Options". From there, you can select the recovery console with the kernel you wanted.

If all else fails, it wouldn't hurt to use a recovery disk to boot into to further diagnose your problems.

Comment: Please take note that the hidden GRUB menu is **a feature and not a bug**. New users will probably never fiddle with GRUB, nor would want to wait a few seconds for the GRUB menu to expire. This is the case for Windows and OSX where recovery/boot/advanced options will be available with the press of a key before the operating system starts.